# A-Frame mouseleave does not change color of cursor

Tags: aframe

I have an app where the user has to answer a question by clicking the correct area on a collada model - there are 2 options and the user knows that an area is selectable when the cursor turns blue (mouse enters the cylinder, which has visible=false).

The mouse turns blue fine, however where the mouse leaves the cylinder, the cursor color should return to black, but instead it stays blue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<a-cursor id="myCursor" color="black"></a-cursor>

<a-entity id='questionA' geometry="primitive: cylinder; height: .01; radius: 2.5" material="color:green; opacity: 1" correctAnswer > </a-entity> 

var cursorVar = document.getElementById('myCursor');
var questionVar = document.getElementById('questionA');

questionVar.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
                cursorVar.setAttribute('color', 'blue');
            });
questionVar.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
                cursorVar.setAttribute('color', 'black');
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor side also emits the event. Try listening to the event from the cursor as a workaround:

```
cursorEl.addEventListener('mouseleave');
```

0.3.0 which should be releasing tomorrow or in two days has improvements on the cursor, raycaster, and raycasting against COLLADA models. This includes the ability to limit what the raycaster tests against which would be ideal in the workaround above.

Could be several factors in your bug, I think once 0.3.0 is out, I'd be able to say with more clarity what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/bryik/pen/GqZjZK) perform as you expect?

I can't see the problem looking at your code (maybe it's something to do with the cursor primitive). Try replacing the cursor primitive with a manually defined one used in the CodePen link above:

```
  <!-- Camera with gaze cursor -->
  <a-entity position="0 1.8 5">
      <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls>
          <a-entity cursor
                  geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.025;
                            radiusInner: 0.015; segmentsTheta: 32"
                  material="color: #283644; shader: flat"
                  raycaster="far: 30"
                  position="0 0 -0.75"
                  id='cursor'>
          </a-entity>
      </a-entity>
  </a-entity>
```

That said, the raycasting does seem a bit inaccurate (with 0.2.0 at least).